# function should return a list of all the indexes in the string that have capital letters

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tried a different approach to what I have seen. Im going through each line of code however I'm not seeing where the issue is with this code

```py
def capital_indexes(s):
    cap_list = []            
    for idx, letter in enumerate(s):
        if letter.isupper() == True:
            cap_list.append(idx)
            return cap_list
```

Answer (score 1):

You return after first iteration!
It should be:

```
def capital_indexes(s):
    cap_list = []            
    for idx, letter in enumerate(s):
        if letter.isupper():
            cap_list.append(idx)
    
    return cap_list
```

And as a oddity, you can (and should!) use [list comprehesion](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists_comprehension.asp) to make code more concise.

```
def capital_indexes(s):
    return [idx for idx, letter in enumerate(s) if letter.isupper()]
```

Answer (score 1):

the Indentation of return is not right, the `return` statement is inside the if statement , so after finding first capital it would exit: the right place is outside the for loop:

```
def capital_indexes(s):
    cap_list = []
    for idx, letter in enumerate(s):
        if letter.isupper():
            cap_list.append(idx)
    return cap_list
```